# Parsing XML and Ordering Node Attributes Automatically by ID in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a question about Python, XML and IDs.

My XML is:

```
<settings>
    <plugin id="1">
            <param id="1" name="mailsend" value="Send Mail" />
            <param id="2" name="mailfunc" value="func/sendmail.py" />
            <param id="3" name="mailfunccount" value="3" />
            <param id="4" name="mailto" value="Mail to" />
            <param id="5" name="mailsub" value="Mail subject" />
            <param id="6" name="mailcont" value="Mail content" />
            <param id="7" name="senderconfigcount" value="2" />
            <param id="8" name="senderid" value="somemail@gmail.com" />
            <param id="9" name="senderpw" value="somepasswd" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin id="2">
            <param id="1" name="taropen" value="Open Tarfile" />
            <param id="2" name="tarfunc" value="func/tarac.py" />
            <param id="3" name="tarfunccount" value="4" />
            <param id="4" name="tarname" value="Tar name" />
            <param id="5" name="tarloc" value="Tar location" />
            <param id="6" name="tardest" value="Tar destination" />
            <param id="7" name="tarstat" value="Delete tar?" />
    </plugin>
</settings>
```

But I couldn't figure how to do the thing in my stackoverflow subject.

I want to order them like this:

```
Send Mail
func/sendmail.py
3
Mail to
Mail subject
Mail content
```

bla bla bla.. When I print it, it only prints Delete tar? part. So, I'm stuck.

My code is:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
myfile = minidom.parse('data/config.xml')

testing = myfile.getElementsByTagName('param')
for node in testing:
    myvar = node.getAttribute('value')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the xml is obviously nested, so your code will need to follow the nesting. You need two nested *for* statements:

```
for plugin in myfile.getElementsByTagName('plugin'):
    print "Plugin "+plugin.getAttribute('id')
    for param in plugin.getElementsByTagName('param'):
        print param.getAttribute('value')
    print
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a little one more question to ask you. If I want to specify one string to print what should I do with ID?